# Robot Framework Sikuli test on VM not starting when triggered through SSH

Tags: ssh, robotframework, ui-automation, sikuli

I have a Sikuli script written in Robot Framework on a Windows VM (Machine-A) to automate a desktop application.This VM has RF and the Desktop application installed.When triggered from this VM locally the automation script runs fine.But my requirement is to trigger it from another Robot script running in a separate Windows VM (Machine-B).
When I tried manually to SSH from Machine-B to Machine-A and trigger RF scripts using robot -t TESTCASENAME Test_Suit_Name the test gets triggered but it soon fails saying no elements found also the screenshot in robot logs show dark screen.
Can any of you please let me know how to resolve this issue.
Also I am using Start Process from Robot Process library to launch the desktop application and it seems that is launching the application behind scenes.

I need to trigger the Robot scripts in Machine-A from Machine-B.The Robot script/Robot framework and desktop application to be tested all are installed in Machine-A.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a setup with RDP, to ensure you have a graphical environment for Sikuli.

If using Oracle VirtualBox, you can enable the "Remote Screen" in the Monitor settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Remote Interface](https://github.com/robotframework/RemoteInterface) instead of SSH.